# .NET WebBrowser control - closing form on unsupported file formats

Tags: .net, winforms, browser

I'll start by mentioning that I'm stuck with the stock `WebBrowser` .NET control so using Gecko or any other alternative is not an option.

I currently have a simple form with an embedded `WebBrowser` control. In another screen, the user selects a file to open, this form pops up and shows the document in the `WebBrowser`. The problem is that, if the file format is supported by this control (say, a JPEG file), it displays properly ; if it's unsupported (TIFF file, for instance), I get the usual "Do you want to open or save this file?" dialog and then the `WebBrowser` displays a "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" page. I don't want this.

What I want to achieve is that, *only* in the second case, when the user has made his choice and an external program opens the file, my form simply closes instead of displaying that page. Is there any event I can handle to achieve this? Is there any possible workaround? Is this even possible?

Thank you all very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can catch the FileDownload-Event and close it then

Comment: Specs have changed so this is not a problem to me anymore but since his looks plausible, I'm setting this as correct answer.